# Biblatex doesn't produce spaces between citations with footcite or footcites

Tags: biblatex

When I use \footcites for multiple citations, I get a semicolon delimited list of citations, but I don't get any space.[image: an example of a poorly formatted citation]

In what may be a related problem, if I use the prenote field in \footcite, I similarly do not get a space between the prenote and the citation. (I've worked around this by using a citation command within \footnote.)

These are my biblatex macros:

```
\RequirePackage[style=historian,autopunct=true,abbreviate=false,citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=historian,backend=biber,isbn=false,language=american,sorting=nyt,pagetracker=false,printseries=true]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
    namedash={---------},%
    volumeof={of},
    editor={Edited by},
    translator={Translated by},
    ibidem={Ibid.},
    phdthesis={Ph.D. diss.,}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Don't define bibliographical strings in ways which are less flexible than the original versions. I'm not sure this is the source of the problem in this case but it is definitely a potential source of other problems. `editor` and `translator` should not be defined that way, for example, and should not be capitalised, in any case. Take a look at the default definitions to see how things are set up there. Although you can't use exactly the same syntax with `\Define...`, it should give you an idea. Why redefine `editor`, `translator` etc.? There are also reported issues with `historian`, though.

Comment: `hostorian` has not been updated for almost three and a half years (last update was in August 2010), `biblatex` has changed quite a bit since then. The problem seems to lie with `historian` throwing about a lot of `\unspace`s that cancel out the `\space` in `\multicitedlim`. Your best bet is probably to find a more recent style and use that. (You load `style=historian`, but then overwrite that by setting `citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=historian`. Is that really what you want?)

Comment: Ahh, I see, if one uses `historian` as the `citestyle` we run into unknown commands (as I said: `hostorian` is quite old). Maybe your best bet is to try `verbose-ibid`, or `biblatex-chicago` (try the former first; it's easier to customise). If you need modifications done to those styles to meet your requirements, just ask another question.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will have a look at verbose-ibid.

Comment: @moewe Want to convert your comments to an answer to get this Q off the list of unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution to this issue, based on comments to the original question, was to stop using `historian`, which is no longer developed, and to switch to a customized `verbose-ibid`.